Issue with proof that SU(2) conjugation on Pauli matrices acts via SO(3)
I want to prove that for a given $U\in SU(2)$, $\phi_U(\vec x)=U\vec x \cdot \vec \sigma U^{\dagger}$ can be identified with a $R(U)=R\in SO(3)$ such that $\phi_U(\vec x)=(R\vec x)\cdot \sigma$.
Seeing that for any $\vec x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ we have that $\phi_U(\vec x)$ is traceless hermatian, it follows that $\phi_U(e_i)$ is a linear combination of $\sigma_i$'s, which justifies the identity $\phi_U(\vec x)=(R\vec x)\cdot \sigma$. We then notice that $\text{det}(\phi_U(\vec x))=-|\vec x|^2=|R\vec x|^2$, so $R\in O(3)$
A simple calculation shows us that $[\vec a \cdot \vec \sigma,\vec b \cdot \vec \sigma]=2i (\vec a \times \vec b) \cdot \vec \sigma$. If we consider $[\phi_U(\vec x),\phi_U(\vec y)]$, we see it is equal to $U[\vec x \cdot \vec \sigma,\vec y \cdot \vec \sigma] U^{\dagger}=2i(R(\vec a \times \vec b)) \cdot \vec \sigma$ and also that $[\phi_U(\vec x),\phi_U(\vec y)]=[(R\vec x) \cdot \vec \sigma,(R\vec y) \cdot \vec \sigma]=2i (R\vec a \times R\vec b) \cdot \vec \sigma=2i\text{det}(R)(R^{-T}(\vec a \times \vec b)) \cdot \vec \sigma=2i\text{det}(R)(R(\vec a \times \vec b)) \cdot \vec \sigma$ This gives us $$2i(R(\vec a \times \vec b)) \cdot \vec \sigma=2i\text{det}(R)(R(\vec a \times \vec b)) \cdot \vec \sigma$$
Which implies $\text{det}(R)=1$. However, I never made use of the fact that $U\in SU(2)$, only that $U\in U(2)$. Yet I cannot see anywhere that I made an unjustified assumption. I would appreciate any help as I cannot make out where I have made an error. I am aware that there are other ways to arrive at this result, but I am more concerned with where the error in this proof lies.

You don’t need the assumption on the determinant. Your map does define a homomorphism from $U(2)$ to $SO(3)$, and when restricted to the subgroup $SU(2)$ gives you the desired homomorphism.
The distinction will be important when determining the kernel of the homomorphism to determine whether the map is many to one. In the first case, the kernel consists of diagonal matrices, so is isomorphic to $U(1)$. In the second case, the kernel is still the leftover diagonal matrices, so is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2$. Btw, to prove that the latter is a double cover, you’ll also need to prove surjectivity.
Hope this helps.

Thank you very much for your response: just to be clear, the proof I outlined is correct, but when we restrict the domain to SU(2) we just get a “nicer” relationship where we can always find exactly 2 elements that map on to any element of SO(3)? But when the domain is U(2) the fibers above a certain element of SO(3) are infinitely large?

Yes, exactly. For any $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$, and $U\in U(2)$, observe that $\phi_U=\phi_{e^{i\theta}U}$.
